# Cómo identificar si el acceso fue por smartphone o computadora

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un proyecto desarrollado con PHP/Mysql/Bootstrap y estoy usando WebView de Java para acceder en Android. Sin embargo, me gustaría diferenciar el valor del producto para quienes acceden a través de la aplicación y a través de la computadora. Ejemplo:

Si el usuario accediera a él a través de la aplicación, el producto tendría un valor. Si se accede a través de la computadora, tendría otro valor. ¿Como puedo hacer eso? Intenté identificarme con el siguiente código, pero no pude.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function checkDevice() { 
    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
    ){
       alert('Acesso por celular'); // está utilizando celular
    }
     else {
       alert('Acesso pelo desktop'); // não é celular
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa que no pudiste? Cuál es el error que obtuviste?

Comment: Lo siento mi español Andres. Al acceder, no identifica si el acceso fue por teléfono o web.

Comment: Puedes mandar un token en un encabezado o como parámetro de la petición.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar cordova: https://cordova.apache.org/

Es un sistema que te permite saber en que entorno te encuentras si móvil o un navegador web. Y es de JS así que te permite dividir correctamente los flujos en función del navegador.

También se puede usar de forma mas específica para navegadores particulares, es bastante potente.

```javascript
if(typeof cordova == 'undefined' || !cordova) { 
   //Web browser JS
} else {
   //Mobile phone JS
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Grismak